# What is the difference between app goes to background and screen locks

Tags: android

I am building a camera app everything works file when i put it to the background but when i explicitly press the lock button it does not work,i am not finding and difference between the callback methods being called or am i missing something please help.

Comment: How are you running it in the background ?

Comment: while recording When I press the home button it stops recording,but when i press lock button explicitly while recording it crashes.I am recording from an async task. Observed all the callback methods all are same in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Put log line inside these methods

```
onPause
onSaveInstanceState
onStop
onDestroy
onResume
onRestoreInstanceState
onStart
onCreate
```

And make sure the same methods are called in both situation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. But, it's helpful. It could help the author to find the differences and in the end to find where is the issue.

Comment: Then you should put it in a comment.

Comment: A comment as in you click "add a comment" under the question and put what you want to say there. This is an answer.